# "Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': Index property setter is not supported." in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs

I updated Chrome latest version i am getting error in angular-ag grid please any one can help me on this.

"Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': Index property setter is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using both cellStyle and cellrenderer for a column? I have faced same issue and was using both cellStyle and cellrenderer for setting css.

Comment: tq this is helpfull for me